# Pad IP addresses with leading 0's - powershell

Tags: powershell, string-formatting, ip-address

I'm looking to pad IP addresses with 0's

example
1.2.3.4 -> 001.002.003.004
50.51.52.53 -> 050.051.052.053

Tried this:

```
[string]$paddedIP = $IPvariable
[string]$paddedIP.PadLeft(3, '0')
```

Also tried split as well, but I'm new to powershell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.Split()` and `-join`.

```
('1.2.3.4'.Split('.') | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.PadLeft(3,'0')}) -join '.'
```

With this approach, you are working with strings the entire time. `Split('.')` creates an array element at every `.` character. `.PadLeft(3,'0')` ensures 3 characters with leading zeroes if necessary. `-join '.'` combines the array into a single string with each element separated by a `.`.

---

You can take a similar approach with the format operator `-f`.

```
"{0:d3}.{1:d3}.{2:d3}.{3:d3}" -f ('1.2.3.4'.Split('.') |
    Foreach-Object { [int]$_ } )
```

The `:dN` format string enables `N` (number of digits) padding with leading zeroes.

This approach creates a string array like in the first solution. Then each element is pipelined and converted to an `[int]`. Lastly, the formatting is applied to each element.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [AdminOfThings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58085951/45375) with a more concise alternative using the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) [with a *script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#scriptblock-substitutions) (`{ ... }`), which requires PowerShell *Core* (v6.1+):

```
PSCore> '1.2.3.50' -replace '\d+', { '{0:D3}' -f [int] $_.Value }

001.002.003.050
```

The script block is called for every match of regex `\d+` (one or more digits), and `$_` inside the script block refers to a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?) instance that represents the match at hand; its `.Value` property contains the matched text (string).

Comment: This is good stuff. I'll need to keep Scriptblock substitutions in mind for Core versions.

Comment: @AdminOfThings: Yes, it's a handy feature, though still somewhat complex, because you need to understand the structure of the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` instance that `$_` refers to.