# Need to pull content from a text file and increment the file name

Tags: powershell

I want to pull the content from a text file which is a filename I want to increment that filename by 1 number. I can't seem to get the right pieces of script together to make this work.

I have a txt file which serves as my log file logfile.txt inside this log file is a file name log_1.txt

I want to get the content of the logfile.txt which should be log_1.txt increment the number so it becomes log_2.txt and then put that back into the log file.

This is what I've been trying to do but keep getting a You cannont call a method on a null-values expression

```
$latest = get-content c:\PS1\Output.txt

$newFileName = $latest.BaseName.Split('_')[0] + "_" + ([int]$latest.BaseName.Split('_')[1] + 1) + $latest.Extension
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$latest` isn't a file object, it's a string. Strings don't have `basename`s. Assuming that your file name stored inside the file matches exactly what you stated, try

```
$OldFileName = Get-Content -Path "C:\PS1\Output.txt"
$FileBaseName,$FileExtension = $OldFileName.Split('.')
$FileBase,$FileIndex = $FileBaseName.Split('_')
$FileIndex += 1
$NewFileName = ($FileBase,$FileIndex -join "_"),$FileExtension -join "."
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide a more concise PowerShell *Core* alternative to [Jeff Zeitlin's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489850/45375):

```
PS> 'log_9.txt' -replace '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)', { 1 + $_.Value }
log_10.txt
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086862/45375) for an explanation of this technique.